# Create word document with headings using c#

Tags: c#

I want to create an word documents with headings for navigation.
In my c# code I created a word document and added a paragraph to it.
I set the style of the added paragraph by this method:

```
paragraph1.Range.set_Style(document.Styles["Heading 1"]);
paragraph.Range.Text="paragraph 1";
```

The result of that code is a word paragraph that is text font and color are as "Heading 1" style but in the navigation pane of the word document there is no navigation tab.

Comment: what library are you using? What type is paragraph/paragraph1/document? is it standard .NET library?

Answer (score 4):

the solution was to set `paragraph1.Range.Text` before setting the style

```
paragraph1.Range.Text = "paragraph 1";
object style_name = "Heading 1";
paragraph1.Range.set_Style(ref style_name);
```

Comment: Please if you found a solution to your problem and decides to share it with the community, please mark it as the correct answer to let people know.

Comment: @SimonJensen i think you can mark the own answere as correct after a few hours? Isn't it? (not sure)

Comment: Thinking about it, I honestly think you are right, but note that the question was asked 19 hours ago, a bit more than a few in my opinion. Anyways, thanks for reminding me tho :)